# jquery: how to find siblings

Tags: jquery, siblings

I have troubles finding the sibling and remove it.
The htlml is: 
< div> < input>< label>< /div>

and the code is :

```
$(#hsdjks label).each(function(){
 // do some stuff ....

  $(this).siblings('input').remove();
});
```

The line $(this) won't work.

Thank you

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: Are the missing quotes in the first selector a typo in the question or in the code?

Comment: Adding to @blgt comment, is ID `hsdjks` correct or element has ID.

Comment: try this :  http://jsfiddle.net/taj3gdn5/1/